# Inner transaction affecting the outer transaction in Spring Boot

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, transactions

I'm trying to fetch data and then process that data in a separate transaction. I have outer method (with outer transaction) and inner method (with inner transaction) for this.

Outer is this:

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, readOnly = true)
public void work() {
    Stream<Item> itemStream = itemRepo.streamAll();
    try {
        List<Object> list = itemStream
                .map(item -> secondService.processItem(item))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(list);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("outer");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    itemRepo.findAll().forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

and inner is this:

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public Integer processItem(Item item) {
    try {
        if (item.getId() == 2) {
            //content
        }
        itemRepo.save(item);
        itemRepo.flush();
        return 0;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("failed");
        return 1;
    }
}
```

So I have a separate transaction for the inner part.

Let's say that I have 3 elements in the stream (and the middle one is with `id=2`)
If the `//content` part is substituted by something that throws a RuntimeException (for example `throw new RuntimeException("inner");`), then all the elements are processed (including the third one that comes after `id=2` one).
If the `//content` part throws `DataIntegrityViolationException` (for example trying to set a `null` value to a `NOT NULL` field), then this exception somehow propagates to the outer transaction and I see

```
org.springframework.transaction.UnexpectedRollbackException: Transaction silently rolled back because it has been marked as rollback-only
```

in the catch part of `work` method. (and since the exception was propagated to outer method the third element in the stream is not processed).

What is happening here? Shouldn't the `processItem` method catch all the exceptions and nothing should roll back the outer transaction?

Is there a way to apply this pattern some other way? Process elements of stream completely independently of other elements in a separate transaction? I'm using Hibernate so I can't use `NESTED` annotation. Not sure if this relevant but the underlying database is Postgres.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52456783/cannot-catch-dataintegrityviolationexception) post on SO points to `DataIntegrityViolationException` being propagated to the end of the transaction, maybe this helps.

Comment: No exception should propogate through that try catch block . Also the `return` statements from within the try catch block and from exception block are not recommended , you can do it better . The post that _Amir Schnell_ shared describes the exception on txn commit , which is outside the scope of the try catch block.