# Spring boot KafkaListener ignoring internal catch

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I using Spring boot with KafkaListener, and i trying to treat internal exceptions (ConstraintViolationException) but i dont know why the internal try catch are not working

So i have the follow code

```java
    @KafkaListener(topics = {"someTopic"},
            groupId = "group_id")
    public void someTopicTreatment(String message) {
        someService.treatmentForSomeTopic(formatMessageToObject(message));
    }
```

In the `treatmentForSomeTopic` code i have

```java
public void treatmentForSomeTopic(String message) {

  try {

    repository.save(message); // this can throw RuntimeException like ConstraintViolationException
  } catch (Exception e) { // IGNORED AND DON'T KNOW WHY
    boolean treated = tryToTreatError();
    if(!treated) {
      throw new CanNotTreatException();
    } 
  }
```

But the problem seem that the Exception is not catched in the treatmentForSomeTopic, is throw direct at the kafka treatment (if i put some try catch in the the method with @KafkaListener i can see the ConstraintViolationException), and i dont understand why.

The stack asked by @tgdavies

```java
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [id_fkey]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:276)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:233)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:566)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:743)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:711)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:654)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:407)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:708)
    at com.nicearma......TreatmentProcessor$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a9f88136.treatmentForSomeTopic(<generated>)
    at com.nicearma......someTopicTreatment(KafkaConsumer.java:38)
```

Comment: Please add the full stack trace of the exception to your question.

Comment: @tgdavies stack trace added (i modify the name of the method to be the same of the example)

Comment: As you can see from the stack trace, the exception is thrown by the TransactionInterceptor which is wrapping your method, so you cannot catch it. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109476/how-to-handle-dataintegrityviolationexception-in-spring

Comment: Related problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52456783/cannot-catch-dataintegrityviolationexception

Comment: You should wrap your tryToTreatError call on its own try / catch block - if it throws an exception, it’ll go straight to the listener method.

Comment: Yes the problem seem to be coming from the transactional, so i changed the transactional to the repository code, that way the try catch get the error emitted in the transaction